# How can I do multiple queries to mongo at one request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let say I have a collection of `Person{email: 'actual email', ..other data}` and want to query if `Person` exists with given `email` and retrieve it data if so or get a null if not.

If i want to do that once than no problem just do a query, through `mongoose` using `Person.findOne()` or whatever.
But what if I have to do a check for 25-100 given emails?  Of course I can just send a tons of requests to mongodb and retrieve the data but it seems a vast of network.

Is there a good and perfomant way to query a mongodb with multiple clauses in single batch like `findBatch([{email: 'email1'}, {email: 'email2'}...{email: 'emailN'} ])` and got as result `[document1,null,document3,null, documentN]` where `null` is for not matched find criterias?

Currently I see only one option:

1. Huge find with single `{email: $in: [] }` query and that do a matching through the searching on the server side in application logic. Cons: quite cumbersome and error prone if you have more than one search criteria.

Is there any better ways to implement such thing?

Comment: yes $in:["email1", "email2"] which translates to: find a document with an email **$in** the list. Well if that's too slow, create an index on `email`.

Comment: no its not, it will return me documents that represents a Persons within given list of emails. But I need a relation between every email and a document if such exist. I.e. if I send  an array of emails I want to retrieve array of same length filled with documents or nulls. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: If you don't include sample docs and sample output no one else will bother to help. FYI. Good luck anyways! Also, this site is worth a try https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

- Replace the arrayOfEmails with your query array
- Replace emailField with the actual name in your db documents

```
db.collName.aggregate([
    {
        "$match" : {
            "emailField" : {
                "$in" : arrayOfEmails
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : null,
            "docs" : {
                "$push" : {
                    "$cond" : [
                        {
                            "$in" : [
                                arrayOfEmails,
                                [
                                    "$emailField"
                                ]
                            ]
                        },
                        "$$ROOT",
                        null
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I got the idea. But there are some issues - db.collName.aggregation it should be .aggregate.  "$in" : [ arrayOfEmails, [ "$emailField"]] are not working properly if arrayOfEmails is an array of email values, but works if it's single string. Do you know if this is expected behaviour?

Comment: tbh, I don't even now how I got that right. It's tough without snippets. Try `"$in":["$emailField", arrayOfEmails]`. Fixed the typo, sorry about that.